# SQL - sub count

Tags: sql, grouping, counting

Hi I've got some SQL ...

```
SELECT  
    AdviceNo,
    Registration
FROM tblSalesDetail
```

that produces something like ...

```
ADV00001, ABC123
ADV00001, CDE564
ADV00002, FGE432
ADV00003, HUY789
ADV00003, MJS532
ADV00003, JFY428
```

Can anyone tell me how I'd adjust it to see the following please?

```
ADV00001, ABC123, 1
ADV00001, CDE564, 2
ADV00002, FGE432, 1
ADV00003, HUY789, 1
ADV00003, MJS532, 2
ADV00003, JFY428, 3
```

Comment: What do the numbers in the final column mean? Are they the number of sales detail records with the given advice no/registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's about Oracle Analytical Functions?

This is a classical example in which RANK is useful ;-)

```
SELECT AdviceNo,
       Registration,
       RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY AdviceNo ORDER BY Registration ASC) MY_RANK
  FROM tblSalesDetail;
```

Comment: Quite a few other DBs support partition by.  SQL Server does and I'm pretty sure DB/2 does as well.  There may be slight platform variations.

Comment: Mr Chicken, your solution works fine in MS SQL 2005 - thank you

Comment: Most of the OP's questions are about .Net and WPF so I guess he's probably using SQL Server.  Note that the equivalent to RANK() in the T-SQL world is row_number().

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` and `partition by` with an `over` clause to reset a count based on groups; the syntax is something like (note, not tested):

```
SELECT  
    AdviceNo,
    Registration,
    row_number() over
    (partition by AdviceNo
     order by Registration)     as Ordinal
FROM tblSalesDetail
```

`partition by` is a bit like `group by` but it doesn't roll up the data - it just resets whatever you are calculating within the partition.  In this case we are computing a row number
using a built in function, and sorting it by Registration within the groups.

[This link to the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) discusses using OVER on T-SQL.   It's basically the same on other platforms that support it.